# Cartoon about girl with tropical hat and monkey companion

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I am looking for a cartoon series about a young white blonde girl that I watched in my childhood, so it was probably from the 90s or early 2000s. I cannot remember much, but the girl usually wore beige clothing and a tropical hat. The whole setting could be located in africa but it could also be somewhere else (but not in the first world). This girl also has a small pet monkey that she carries around everywhere. The girl could be an orphan, but she might also be just separated from her parents. I have not seen the whole show so I cannot tell this for sure. The tone of the series as far as I remember is rather serious and not silly/funny. Especially in the one episode that I remember:

My most striking memory is one episode where heavy rainfall has caused a flood. The girl is on one side of a swollen river (on some kind of natural dam?) and urgently needs to get a message across to someone standing on the other side, who is definitely out of earshot. She then sends her monkey with a message over some kind of strut or pipe (definitely too small to be traversed by a human) that spans the river. The episode ends with the uncertainty whether the monkey will make it across in time.

Comment: Was there anything particularly science fictional or fantastical about this cartoon series?

Comment: No, it was rather realistic.

Comment: In that case I'm voting to close this question because it is not about a work that contains science fictional or fantasy related elements

Comment: @fez my mind immediately went to The Wildthornberys, which is SFF I think?

Comment: @fez That is unfortunate. Is one of the other SE sites on-topic for this question?

Comment: @And I don't think so, unfortunately. [movies.se] banned identification questions, although they have a [resource listing](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129/27759) other (non-SE) sites that might be helpful for identifying movies or TV series.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I would definitely say so, I'm quite surprised we don't have any questions about The Wild Thornberrys already

Comment: I just found out via reddit that I was looking for "Bush Baby" if anyone else is interested.